# How can you display values within a node-set when retrieving them using a function?

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

I have a stylesheet called FourColumnTable that I want to use as a table template. At the moment it looks like this and uses the xml shown below it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template name="FourColumnTable">
        <xsl:param name="rows" />

        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Age</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Age</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <xsl:variable name="itemCount" select="count($rows/*)" />

        <xsl:if test="$itemCount &gt; 1">
            <xsl:for-each select="$rows/MyTableData">
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="age" /></td>
                            <td>blank for now</td>
                            <td>blank for now</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The data is retrieved using a function that returns some xml as a string. The xml looks like this:

```
<MyDataSet>
  <MyTableData>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <age>25</age>
  </MyTableData>
  <MyTableData>
    <name>Karen</name>
    <age>36</age>
  </MyTableData>
  <MyTableData>
    <name>Frank</name>
    <age>58</age>
  </MyTableData>
</MyDataSet>
```

I have an email template that currently works and that I now want to put this table into it. So at the moment I'm doing the following:

```
<xsl:template name="CustomerData">
  <xsl:call-template name="FourColumnTable">
    <xsl:with-param name="rows" select="msxml:node-set(myFunctions:GetCustomerData())" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

At the moment this seems to create a node-set, but when I try and use it in the `for-each` it doesn't show any values. I've tried removing the `if statement` and then doing the following:

- for the `for-each` select statement changing it to "$rows/MyDataSet/*".
- for the `for-each` select statement changing it to "$rows/MyDataSet/MyTableData".
- for the `for-each` select statement changing it to "$rows/node()" and then in the first column for the select statement of the 'value-of' adding "$rows/node()". This displayed all of the data as per the xml, so I know $rows at least has the data.

I've tried variations of the above but those seem to be the main tests worth mentioning. What I can't understand is why it will return the data for everything, but I'm unable to loop through for specific nodes (MyTableData nodes). Help please.

***UPDATE***

Here is my function `GetCustomerData()`:

```
public string GetCustomerData()
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

    xmlDoc.LoadXml(this.GetAllCustomerData());

    var nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/MyTableData");

    if (nodeList != null && nodeList.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {
            sb.Append(node.InnerText + EnvironmentNewLine);
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I'm guessing this needs to return an `XmlDocument` instead? However, my GetAllCustomerData method returns a lot more than what I need, which is why I select the nodes I want. Can I take this `XmlNodeList` and turn that into an XmlDocument?

***UPDATE 2***

I opted to change my function to simply return the xml document as is and then in my table template alter what nodes I iterate over within the `foreach` statement like this:

```
public XmlDocument GetCustomerData()
{
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); 
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(this.GetAllCustomerData());

    return xmlDoc;
}
```

This allowed me to iterate over what I needed.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually an XML document fragment you're passing in? You said the function returns xml as a string, the node-set you're passing in might just contain a single text node with the markup. As a test, put dummy data in your `<xsl:param name="rows"><MyDataset>etc..</MyDataset></xsl:param>`, and see if that works without passing anything in.

Comment: We don't have enough here to reproduce the problem. You should do a test and see what `<xsl:copy-of select="myFunctions:GetCustomerData()"/>` returns. -- P.S. Your stylesheet says version 2.0, but you seem to be using an XSLT 1.0 processor.

Comment: @Flynn1179 - it looks like this is the issue. I created some test data (basically a replica of mine, just less of it) and it worked fine. So it looks like it's just a string. I'm guessing I'll need to alter the function to return an XMLDocument.

Comment: You will need to tell us which XSLT processor you use to allow us to help. The data structures to be exchanged between C# and XSLT are highly processor specific. And currently you show an XPath selection of `xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/MyTableData");` which would select the root element named `MyTableData`, I am not sure what the code trying to iterate over that list (there can only be one root element) is supposed to achieve.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - if I understand you correctly, I'm using version 1.0 (as per my first line of code). When debugging I can see that it's loading the xml into `xmlDoc` and gives me the `XmlNodeList` I want. It seems just the matter of returning nodeList in such a way that I can use it, which I'm guessing is XmlDocument?

Comment: I was asking about the XSLT processor (e.g. Microsoft's `XslCompiledTransform` or Saxon's `Processor` or XmlPrime's processor) you are using with .NET or C#. If you are using XslCompiledTransform then you can return any implementation of XPathNavigator or XPathNodeIterator, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxaw5z5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your custom function is not returning an xml document or document fragment, it's probably just a string, but without being able to see that function I can't say for sure.

In other words, you've got the equivalent of

```
<xsl:param name="rows">&lt;MyDataSet&gt;Data&lt;/MyDataSet&gt;</xsl:param>
```

instead of

```
<xsl:param name="rows"><MyDataSet>Data</MyDataSet></xsl:param>
```

And you're not able to process is as XML, because it's not, it's just the markup. Calling node-set on it doesn't parse it into XML, it turns it into a set of one text node.

Comment: This appears to be the problem. So, to resolve it I'm guessing I need to return an XmlDocument rather than string from my function?

Comment: To be honest, if you're pulling data from an XML document like that, don't bother. Just return xmlDoc as soon as you've loaded it, and pick out what you need in your XSLT. I've never actually create an extension function that returns XML myself, but I'm guessing you can probably return either the document itself or the root element. Unless of course there's a huge amount of other data you don't need that might affect performance.

Comment: Yeah, I've gone with that. I've pulled the whole xml document, then within the `for-each` just selected the nodes I want to iterate over. Marked this as correct as it answered my initial question.